# How to get data from two models in Django

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models

I have been trying to use with the a legacy database. I have created models file using inscpectdb but now I am not able to perform joins on the table.

I have two tables job_info and  username_userid.

Here is my models.class file:

```
class UseridUsername(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'userid_username'

class LinuxJobTable(models.Model):
    job_db_inx = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    mod_time = models.IntegerField()
    account = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    exit_code = models.IntegerField()
    job_name = models.TextField()
    id_job = models.IntegerField()
    id_user = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'linux_job_table'
```

Heren is my serializable class :

```
class UseridUsernameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UseridUsername
        fields = ('userid','username')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    username =  UseridUsernameSerializer(many=False)
    model = LinuxJobTable
    fields = ('account','mod_time','username')
```

Comment: First of all I would suggest to add a relation between LinuxJobTable and UseridUsername tables. Once a relation is there, you won't need to explicitly make a join between these two tables.

Comment: I have tried doing it. I did: 

id_user = models.ForeignKey(
        UseridUsername,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    ) 

But it gives me error: "Unknown column 'linux_job_table.id_user_id' in 'field list'

Comment: This is because Django adds `_id` after the name of the relation fields to create a column in database. You can define `db_column` attribute to prevent this default behaviour. Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Comment: If you don't want to add relation, just add method calling user from jobtable model. Though it will hit database once more.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal: Thanks. I did: id_user = models.OneToOneField(UseridUsername , on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column="id_user").But how do I get username now?

Comment: Query LinuxJobTable and through the object (say obj) run `obj.id_user.username` should give you the username.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal : Thanks.That solved the issue.